# resolve dependencies for maven project spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

**pom.xml admin-service**

```
<parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>sai-edm-adminpanel</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>sai-edm-adminpanel</name>
        <description>sai-edm-adminpanel</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
```

**pom.xml authorization service(which depends on the admin service)**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>sai-edm-auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sai-edm-auth</name>
    <description>sai-edm-auth</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>sai-edm-adminpanel</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

when deploying the project gives me an error "Failed to execute goal on project sai-edm-auth: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.springframework:sai-edm-auth:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.springframework:sai-edm-adminpanel:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone) -> [Help 1]"

The project is launched locally, the problem is only when deploying, tell me what could be the problem, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot use the *groupId* "com.springframework" at it is not yours. See the [Maven Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html). So for both artifacts *sai-edm-adminpanel* and *sai-edm-adminpanel* change the groupId to something you own.

Secondly, remove the *compile* scope line.

Thirdly, make sure that you have *sai-edm-adminpanel* artifact installed in your local m2 repository. You can find your local repo under `~/.m2/repository/`. If you cannot find it there, you first must install it by going to the *sai-edm-adminpanel* pom.xml and running `mvn clean install`.